# Special Login with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

The company where i am currently working has a special kind of authentication process.

Indeed, several users can have the same login and password. So, to identify them, in a second time, the user has to give his email. But again, in a few cases, several users can be concerned and then, the user has to give his company id to be full authenticated.

So, my problem is that in some cases, the authentication process **cannot be done in one step**, which is the default behaviour of most applications that Spring Security handles out of the box.

So my question is : what is the simpliest way to implement with Spring Security this **special login process** ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had to do a similar two-step authentication process.   It sounds simple, but finding the right places to inject and the right methods to override was not easy.   The basic idea is to provide another role for the intermediate authentication (the email check), then grant full access after the email is confirmed.

Hopefully the code below provides some good hints on how it could be solved for your scenario.

Create a custom UserDetailsChecker to handle post-authentication checks.   This is where the user's role is determined.

```
public class CustomPostAuthenticationChecks implements UserDetailsChecker {

        public void check(UserDetails userDetails) {

            CustomUser customUser = (CustomUser) userDetails;
            if (customUser.needsEmailAuthentication()) {
                // Get rid of any authorities the user currently has
                userDetails.getAuthorities().clear();
                // Set the new authority, only allowing access to the 
                // email authentication page.
                userDetails.getAuthorities().add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_NEEDS_EMAIL_AUTH"));
            } else {
                userDetails.getAuthorities().add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_AUTHORIZED_USER"));
            }
    }
```

Create a custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler.   This class sends the user to the correct URL based on their role.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

@Override
protected String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String targetUrl = null;

    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();

    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = securityContext.getAuthentication().getAuthorities();

    if (authorities.contains(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_NEEDS_EMAIL_AUTH"))) {
        targetUrl = "/authenticate";
    } else if (authorities.contains(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_AUTHORIZED_USER"))) {
        targetUrl = "/authorized_user_url";
    } else {
        targetUrl = super.determineTargetUrl(request, response);
    }

    return targetUrl;
}
```

After the user's email address is authenticated, you will need to grant the user full access to the application:

```
public void grantUserAccess(User user) {
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    Authentication auth = securityContext.getAuthentication();
    user.getAuthorities().clear();
    user.getAuthorities().add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_AUTHORIZED_USER"));
    Authentication newAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, auth.getCredentials(), user.getAuthorities());
    securityContext.setAuthentication(newAuth);
}
```

Define a custom authentication provider to register your CustomPostAuthenticationChecks:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="YourAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="postAuthenticationChecks">
        <bean class="CustomPostAuthenticationChecks"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

If you're using the standard form-login tag, you can easily define your custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler:

```
<security:form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler">

...

<bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
```

Add a new role intercept rule for the **/authenticate** URL, so only users who need more authentication can access that page.

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/authenticate/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_NEEDS_EMAIL_AUTH')" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/authorized_user_url/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_AUTHORIZED_USER')" />
```

Comment: oh thanks a lot Brad. That's why i need and you won't believe me if i tell you that i was doing something very similar when i saw your answer! However, i did not plan to use a customAuthenticationProvider. I planned to use a custom UserDetailsService only where i retrieve the user and i determine the role. Do you think it is right ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you grant them authorities in the UserDetailsService, what happens if their username/password do not match and a BadCredentialsException is thrown.   The password check is done after the UserDetailsService loads the user, so would they be left with the "ROLE_NEEDS_EMAIL_AUTH" authority?

Comment: oh ok. I did not know that UserDetailsService was just to retrieve the user by his username and that's all. And what is the best way to keep the username and password in the session (or anywhere else) in order to perform the second check with the email?

Comment: Ok, i had that question because when i retrieved the user by calling the SecurityContextHolder and Authentication, i had a null password. But in fact, it was because i was using the latest version 3.1 of Spring Security and in this version, the credentials are erased by default after the user is authenticated. It is not the case in Spring Security 3.0.5 where they are not erased by default. I don't know if it is worth to erase it after all...